# Linux - Permissions to Create Directory / Delete Directory and Files / Change Permission for an entire Drive

Tags: linux, directory, permissions, ubuntu-20.04

I need your help, in order to allow me, to create directories, delete files, save files in directories. Right now, I'm unable to do anything in this Drive "Ubuntu-Dados".
I've already tried a bunch varieties of commands, from this site, and including running Nautilus, "sudo chmod -R -v 777 *", and nothing is working. Below is the result of my attempt to this issue. **I need access to do anything in this Drive.** - I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

[image]

Comment: Care to translate the error messages?  The underlying filesystem could be mounted read-only...  Also the image contains only text, so it should be cut-paste as text in the question, and not link external images.

Comment: The Error messages says: "System of files only for reading"  if you look at my commands,  you will see that they didn't work, none of them. Returning the same message.  "Sistema de arquivos somente para leitura" => it means: "system of files only for reading". I can't delete or save any file in these directories and nor create a new  directory. Even changing the files with sudo chmod 777 'filename.txt' .

Comment: Ah so your filesystem is mounted with `ro` (read only) option.  Run `mount`, it will show you all your filesystems, you should see ro in the options for the one you are trying to modify.  Only solution, `umount` it and `mount` it back with `rw` permissions.

Comment: "command run not found" can you provide me with more instructions in details to solve this problem. I'm a new user with Linux. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Look at the documentation for Ubuntu sysadmin, it details how to unmount and mount filesystems with options.

Comment: Thank you very much for  your support. I'll do that. Best regards.